# Why is Chromium blocking DefaultSearchProviderEnabled Group policy?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, chromium, group-policy, gpo

I am trying to change the `DefaultSearchProvider` of Chromium browser using the group policies. I followed https://chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#DefaultSearchProviderEnabled this documentation. I can see the policies in `chrome://policy/` but the problem is that the `DefaultSearchProviderEnabled` is being **blocked** by Chrome and I am getting an error message:

> This policy is blocked, its value will be ignored.

I have attached the screenshots of my group policy Registry keys and `chrome://policy` page. Please tell me if I am doing anything wrong?

I am using Chromium version: 78.0.3875.0

[chrome Policy Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6nqt.jpg)

[Group Policy registry keys screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKwj3.jpg)

Comment: From https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=DefaultSearchProviderEnabled there is following statement: 

 This policy is available only on Windows instances that are joined to
 a Microsoft® Active Directory® domain. or Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise
 instances that enrolled for device management.

Comment: Thanks, however I read it earlier. Anyways thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are need Windows Server for that. It is for security.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).